# Store A Range/Multiple Ranges in SQL Database

Tags: oracle, rdbms, sqldatatypes

I want to store ranges in an SQL table column. For example [4-10],[14-18), and then filter the rows with a query like

`select * from table_name where range_column contains 16;`

I am more interested in oracle, but would also like to know if any other databases have a datatype that allows this.

I understand that this can be done using multiple rows and two columns `range_begin` and `range end` but I want to know if there is a  datatype that can do this using a single column.

Comment: In Oracle the only way with a single column could be a string, for example `'[4-10)'`, but I would prefer some more columns, but a more usable data; as an aside, 2 columns would not be enough if you can have non integer values and "open" intervals (not sure about the word) such as `[4-10)`

Comment: Postgres does indeed have a native [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) for this with very efficient support for indexing. To store multiple ranges you would need an array of ranges, e.g. `int4range[]` (I am unsure however, if _that_ can be indexed efficiently)

Comment: is this a range of integers or a range of floating point numbers?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a simple built-in way to do this with native data types.

This doesn't keep the two separate ranges in the form you showed, but you could use a nested table that holds all the values within the ranges:

```
create type range_type as table of number
/

create table table_name (id number, range_column range_type)
nested table range_column store as range_tab;
```

Clearly for large ranges the storage requirements are going to be higher than only storing the low and high values.

A significant issue then becomes how you populate it from your original range data, and how you maintain it - since the demarcation of the original ranges is lost. For a set of contiguous values, you can't tell if the collection was built from a single range, or more than one contiguous or even overlapping ranges.

You could set your ranges up like this, but how you'd really do it depends on how you get the low/high values for the ranges in the first place:

```
insert into table_name (id, range_column)
values (1, cast(multiset(
   select level + 3 from dual connect by level <= 7
) as range_type));

insert into table_name (id, range_column)
values (2, cast(multiset(
   select level + 25 from dual connect by level <= 5
) as range_type));

insert into table_name (id, range_column)
values (3, cast(multiset(
   select level + 3 from dual connect by level <= 7
   union select level + 13 from dual connect by level <= 5
) as range_type));
```

Your query would then be:

```
select * from table_name where 16 member of range_column;

        ID RANGE_COLUMN                                                
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
         3 RANGE_TYPE(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18)
```

If you wanted to keep the ranges separately identifiable you could use an object type to hold the low and high values, and then use a nested table of those, though the query becomes more complicated:

```
create type range_object as object(low number, high number)
/

create type range_type as table of range_object;
/

create table table_name (id number, range_column range_type)
nested table range_column store as range_tab;

insert into table_name (id, range_column)
values (1, range_type(range_object(4, 10)));

insert into table_name (id, range_column)
values (2, range_type(range_object(25, 5)));

insert into table_name (id, range_column)
values (3, range_type(range_object(4, 10), range_object(14, 18)));

select t.* from
table_name t
cross join table(t.range_column) r
where 16 between r.low and r.high;

        ID RANGE_COLUMN(LOW, HIGH)
---------- -----------------------------------------------------
         1 RANGE_TYPE(RANGE_OBJECT(4, 10), RANGE_OBJECT(14, 18))
```

Neither seems particularly appealing when compared with a separate table of ranges with low/high values; neither does storing a string representation of the ranges and having a function to figure out if a given number is in them, not least as validating the format of the ranges would be a pain.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle 12.1 introduced a new syntax that makes it easier to deal with ranges.  Unfortunately it only works for dates but it can be twisted to work with numbers.

Normally I would not recommend any solution that stores data as the wrong type.  Only use this if there is a dire need for a more convenient range syntax.

Create the table using dates and the `PERIOD FOR` clause:

```
--drop table table_name;
create table table_name
(
    id number,
    range_begin date,
    range_end   date,
    period for table_name_period(range_begin, range_end)
);
```

Insert the data, converting it to dates with the `'J'` format model.  This uses the Julian date format, which counts the number of days from 4712 BC.  Dates only go to the year 9999 which means this solution only works for numbers between 0 and 5373484.

```
insert into table_name values (1, to_date(4, 'J'), to_date(10, 'J'));
insert into table_name values (2, to_date(14, 'J'), to_date(18, 'J'));
commit;
```

Now the comparison condition can be simplified.

```
select id, to_number(to_char(range_begin, 'J')) begin, to_number(to_char(range_end, 'J')) end
from table_name
as of period for table_name_period to_date(16, 'J');

ID   BEGIN   END
--   -----   ---
2       14    18
```

There's a lot of ugly conversion in the above code.  They can be simplified with some simple functions to do the date to number conversion.

```
--Date-to-number.
create or replace function d2n(p_date date) return number is
begin
    return to_number(to_char(p_date, 'J'));
end;
/

--Number-to-date.
create or replace function n2d(p_number number) return date is
begin
    return to_date(p_number, 'J');
end;
/
```

The code looks better with the functions.

```
select id, d2n(range_begin) begin, d2n(range_end) end
from table_name
as of period for table_name_period n2d(16);
```

This is still a mess and probably only good for some extreme cases.  Hopefully a future version of Oracle will extend the range syntax to work with numbers.

Comment: -1 for this hack.  I think it is not a good idea to misuse the date datatype. And you do not only misuse the date datatype you also misuse the period feature. This feature is used to define the temporal validity of the row. I don't think there are effective indexes for periods implemented (I think this is not necessary for the intended purpose)